# Titanium Studio nodejs debugging

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I would like to debug a .js file containing some mocha tests in titanium studio, is there any plugin to do so?

I've tried to install the nodeclipse plugin but I'm not allowed to install it.

Answer (score 0):

it may be out , but did you try : http://www.jshint.com/

it won't understand Ti.* but it will correct some basic javascript error.

otherwise you can lunch your test with an titanium emulator, and take a look to the stack trace. (feel sad doing it , too);

Comment: Thank but I would like to do proper debugging. For now I keep using a different IDE for that!